# Attributing a software library which uses another library

Tags: apache-2.0, license-notice, attribution

I'm using this library in my app:
[AndroidPhotoFilters library](https://github.com/ravi8x/AndroidPhotoFilters)

The problem is, that it uses some other library (link: [Original AndroidPhotoFilters library](https://github.com/Zomato/AndroidPhotoFilters)) with some minor changes, I guess. Who to attribute in my app's About page? And how to, because License section just says - "This library falls under Apache v2". What year & owner to put in Apache license section in attribution page?

Comment: "License section just says - 'This library falls under Apache v2'" - That's not all it says. See the LICENSE file of the project you linked to.

Comment: @Brandin I saw it already. It links to whole Apache 2.0 T&C. I'm confused what to put in the place of year & owner when attributing, by including standard 2 paragraph Apache license in my app.

Comment: Why do you need to write the year and owner as part of your About page? If you want to, you may, but the Apache license does not require that. See Section 4d if the Apache license.

Comment: Your title would be clearer as "Attributing a software library which is forked from another library". You appear to be using a fork (i.e. a modified version) of an Apache licensed library.

Comment: Should I point to the relevant license then? By pasting a link?

Comment: See [I'm using 2 libraries licensed under Apache 2.0. How do I comply if my app is proprietary software and I'm not modding the libraries?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/7499/im-using-2-libraries-licensed-under-apache-2-0-how-do-i-comply-if-my-app-is-pr)